# jQuery UI selectmenu does not open when clicking the span for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```js
(function dropdownInit() {
  var myDropdown = $("#myDropdown");
  myDropdown.selectmenu();
})();

$(document).on(
  "keyup click change beforecut selectionchange",
  "#myTextArea",
  function(e) {
    setButtons();
  }
);

function setButtons() {
  var textArea = $("#myTextArea");
  var myDropdown = $("#myDropdown");
  if (textArea.length && textArea.val().length > 0) {
    myDropdown.attr("disabled", false);
    toggleDropdown();
  } else {
    myDropdown.selectedIndex = 0;
    myDropdown.attr("disabled", true);
    toggleDropdown();
  }
}

function toggleDropdown() {
  var myDropdown = $("#myDropdown");

  if (myDropdown.attr("disabled")) {
    myDropdown.addClass("myInput--disabled");
  } else {
    myDropdown.removeClass("myInput--disabled");
  }
  myDropdown.selectmenu("refresh");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.myContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.myDropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myDropdown:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.textArea {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.myDropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-selectmenu-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.ui-selectmenu-menu.ui-selectmenu-open {
  display: block;
}

.ui-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.ui-selectmenu-button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-selectmenu-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="myContainer" id="app">
      <textarea id="myTextArea" class="textArea"></textarea>
      <select id="myDropdown" class="myDropdown" disabled="disabled">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My code is running a function that triggers on `keyup click change beforecut selectionchange` of a textarea. Basically, at the end of the function I am calling the `refresh` method of the selectmenu, since I want to apply different styles for the disabled state. As you probably know, this updates the `ui-id` of the element, which according to me is the main cause of my issue. I observe the following behaviour:

Writing in the text area enables the selectmenu. Moreover, every keystroke changes the `ui-id`. If,  afterwards, I click directly on the text containing span of the selectmenu, it doesn't open, but the `ui-id` gets changed again, instead. Clicking a second time on the selectmenu opens it, and the `ui-id` **does not** get changed.

I can't remove the `change` event, because it includes copy/pasting by right clicking. In addition, I want to make it more generic, because the selectmenu is a common component for my app, used many times. in different pages.

P.S. Keep in mind that the project is a lot more complex than the snippet shown.

Comment: Please, share some code that we can reproduce.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You need to post your [mcve] here

Comment: So, I was able to solve my problem, by removing all the events and putting "input" in the handler. Works fine and covers every case of inputting text.